# Horror movie involving a couple trapped in a petrol station with a black spikey creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I think this is only a few years old. 2008-2011 maybe?

A young couple on an American highway pulls into a gas station. Somehow, this odd black spikey creature follows them or turns up there.

I think it's about the size of a tennis ball. It infects people at the gas station and they start sprouting black thorns and spikes, they lose control of their limbs and eventually their bodies and start attacking other people at the gas station.

It almost sounds like a comedy, but it definitely isn't.

Comment: Sounds like [Legion](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0079273/?ref_=tt_cl_t11) starring Paul Bettany. But it also sounds like a common trope as well.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This sounds like one of my favourite horror movies, [*Splinter*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1031280/):

> Trapped in an isolated gas station by a voracious Splinter parasite that transforms its still-living victims into deadly hosts, a young couple and an escaped convict must find a way to work together to survive this primal terror.

Comment: Yeah that's it! Much appreciated 