# Sci fi horror movie where people hide in a gas station from a black type ooze creature

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I remember the movie was based in or near Louisiana. The creature was a black type ooze and attacked by body heat. The folks hid in gas station in a cooler from the creature and at one point a state trooper gets killed by the creature.

Comment: possibly the same as https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117330/identify-this-horror-movie-couple-trapped-in-a-petrol-station-black-spikey-cr

Answer (score 8):

This is [*Splinter*](https://m.imdb.com/title/tt1031280/) (2008).

> Trapped in an isolated gas station by a voracious Splinter parasite that transforms its still-living victims into deadly hosts, a young couple and an escaped convict must find a way to work together to survive this primal terror.

Comment: It was a fun movie, and I knew it when I saw that question this morning. :)

Comment: Sounds like a reboot of The Blob, with Steve McQueen: https://m.imdb.com/title/tt0051418/  Trapped in a diner, not a gas station. Great movie!

Answer (score 0):

Dean R Koontz wrote a book featuring a monster like this.  Title "Phantoms."  I found it an unputdownable terrifying read.

Comment: Which, there was a movie adaptation of it, but I don't think it had them trapped in a gas station.